# image files not being loaded on iPod

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have some image files in my ios project, and all the images/resources load successfully on the simulator, but some files do not load when i test my project on iPod. What things should I verify?

Comment: I think some more information would be helpful: - Which iOS SDK version? How do you load the files (using UIImage imageWithName: or perhaps you have just placed them on a view in IB)?

Comment: `File System Path` can be the problem.

Comment: Check the capitalisation on the file names. Device is case sensitive, simulator is not.

Comment: ios sdk version is 6...and I load them using [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] for example.

Comment: There are no issues with case sensitivity..I get an error when I try to make a build..error copying png..thanks for your responses

Answer (score 0):

Image file names are case-sensitive. Suppose your image name is Abc.png. If you write down abc.png then the image will load on simulator but it will not in device